# Trigger lambda on dynamodb table to send email

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I want to trigger lambda when there is a insertion in dynamo db table and sending email (using sns/ses) to a particular email id ..

Comment: OK. So what have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

You have the answer in your question itself.

> DynamoDB -- (Enable DynamoDB Streams Trigger) Lamba (use SES to send email)